# simple foreground Android audio playback: shall I use MediaPlayer/Exoplayer in Service?

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer, exoplayer

I need to embed simple inline audio playback into a list view, where the user would just click play/pause/stop on the items one by one, in the foreground
The playback back would stop when leaving the screen (activity or fragment).
So the use case is similar to those usual chat apps.

Ideally, I was looking for a simple UI widget I could embed into a list view and pass a mp3/wav/ogg url (local files for a start).

Trying to research for such a thing I found people implementing either an ultra simplistic player with no ui at all or a fully fledged bound Service (which I tried and it works, but it seems like an overkill for a simple foreground playback). When simply embedding a MediaPlayer + MediaController into a fragment, the android monitor was complaining -I think- about doing too much on the UI thread.

So, is there such a player widget to minimise boilerplate code?

Would ExoPlayer be a good choice? ( I see it's powerful but may be even more of an overkill - unless it has some handy utility class, which I missed so far)

What would be the simplest, quickest, safest, most elegant solution?

I'd be grateful for any pointers or enlightenment.

Answer (score -1):

In the meantime I found some potential candidates as *audio player widgets*:

- Uncodin: looks good but not properly packaged, as a gradle dependency https://github.com/Uncodin/Android-Common/blob/master/UncodinCommon-standalone/src/in/uncod/android/media/widget/AudioPlayerView.java
- https://github.com/Cleveroad/MusicBobber
- and more on android-arsenal.com

I've yet to try these but wouldn't mind hearing suggestions about concrete solutions or how to implement or where to look.

Comment: Why would someone just -1 a self answer (that also happens to the only one so far), without justification or providing a more correct answer?